# SQL query to select rows for data value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I would like to pull all records where the Value for an ID changed.  For example, I want to write a query to pull ID 1 where Date and Value change. I also want to pull the old and the new records from this dataset:

```
Date      ID  Value
1/1/2015    1   5
2/2/2016    2   1
3/3/2017    1   7
4/4/2017    3   4
5/1/2017    2   1
5/6/2017    1   8
```

Desired results:

```
Date    ID  Value
1/1/2015    1   5
3/3/2017    1   7
5/6/2017    1   8
```

As was pointed out below, I have to pull over 200,000 unique IDs so ID = 1 will not work.

Comment: Hint:  `WHERE ID = 1`.

Comment: Haha of course.  I should have specified this is for a dataset with over a 200,000 individual IDs.

Answer (score 1):

Here (in the subquery), we simply select the id's where min(Value) is not equal to the max(value).  Then a simple join to display the detail.

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([Date] varchar(50),[ID] int,[Value] int)
Insert Into @YourTable Values
 ('1/1/2015',1,5)
,('2/2/2016',2,1)
,('3/3/2017',1,7)
,('4/4/2017',3,4)
,('5/1/2017',2,1)
,('5/6/2017',1,8)

Select A.*
 From  @YourTable A
 Join (
        Select ID
         From @YourTable
         Group By ID
         Having min(Value)<>max(Value)
      ) B  on A.ID=B.ID
```

**Returns**

```
Date        ID  Value
1/1/2015    1   5
3/3/2017    1   7
5/6/2017    1   8
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I will try this tomorrow and let you know how it goes!

Comment: My list of values is in the hundreds of thousands and with two hundred columns.  Is it possible to list, just * for all?

Comment: @lpd983 The number of rows is not important.  I would suggest unpivoting the data and group by id, attribute.  Let me know if you need assistance

Answer (score 0):

You can use trigger to capture inserted, updated and deleted records. Use `Select * from deleted` to find deleted records and `Select * from Inserted` to find inserted records. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/triggers/use-the-inserted-and-deleted-tables for details.